# How to retrieve a array of IDs from MySQL database and use them with a curl command?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have never coded with PHP or interacted with a database before.

I need to retrieve a list of IDs from table `data` where `type = 2` or other values and then use curl to interact with a remote PHP script.

The redacted curl command is this:

```
curl 'https://link.php?csrf_token=token&action=start&id=11520&server_id=7' -H 'cookie: __cfduid=d086aa5352e22495ebb66a655cb822df51564250721; PHPSESSID=718567f3940e84a72458fad7200de019'
```

The only thing I need to change in this command is `&id=XXXX` from the list we just fetched and a way to get a `csrf_token`

If it helps this is the curl command I captured with chrome to login with some redacted information

```
curl 'https://link/index.php?action=login' -H 'authority: example.com' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'origin: https://example.com' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'dnt: 1' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'referer: https://domain/index.php' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5' -H 'cookie: __cfduid=d086aa5352e22495ebb66a655cb822df51564250721; PHPSESSID=718567f3940e84a72458fad7200de019' --data 'login=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD' --compressed
```

I managed to build this code:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname;
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user,$pass);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`data` WHERE `type`=2;";
$ps = $db->prepare($query);
$ps->execute();
$result = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But don't know how to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the ids from the database. You can do that thus:

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

You can then look at the id list using this:

```
print_r($ids);
```

From there, you need to add a list using query strings. You could do something like this:

```
$idList = 'id=' . implode('&id=', $ids);
```

This will start the list with "id=", and then intersperse "&id=" between each id in the list. If there is only one id, then you will get:

> id=1

If there is two, then:

> id=1&id=2

and so forth. From here, you can echo this out to see what it looks like:

```
echo "$idList\n";
```

You can then feed that into your curl call.

### Security

When injecting data into a command line call, we have to be careful with user input, in case the user finds a way of escaping from a parameter and executing their own shell commands. However, in this case we are safe, since the id list can only ever contain integers (assuming the definition of the column is also an integer).

Comment: Fetch id from database and use in the curl call

Comment: OK, I've changed my answer @Freedo. Try that, and see if you can get the various debugging outputs to work. Once you are happy with your string list of ids, it can be fed into a curl call. However, don't worry about curl to start with - one thing at a time.